# Whenever i tried to root my Xolo a1010 it always shows an error, How can i root my device.?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I want to root my device XOLO A1010, whenever i try to root it with kingoroot, kingroot, frameroot it shows an error occured. Pleae help me to get my phone rooted..

Answer (score 0):

Try rooting using **PC**. Some good softwares are available to root the phone directly.
If pc method fails, then try rooting by flashing **[SuperSU zip](https://download.chainfire.eu/696/supersu/)** via a **custom recovery** for your device, which you will need to flash to your device via `fastboot` or similar.

Comment: Stock recovery won't work. Custom recovery is the only way, which needs to be pre-flashed using `fastboot` or similar.